# Odd result from SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query. I have removed the inner workings but shown the black-box effect of the result.

The whole query doesn't return {0,10,5,-2,10} as it should, instead it returns {0,0,0,0,0} and I cannot understand why the partition-by line is affecting it???

If I exclude the `WHERE rn = 1` condition, it works correctly. Therefore for some reason the row number is not getting viewed properly.

I think the problem is specific to the values {0,10,5,-2,10} for whatever reason because when I call this function with different parameters, the values return fine.

```
SELECT  Col1, isnull(Col2,0) AS Col11, isnull(Col4,0) AS Col4, isnull(q.Col3,0) AS Col3, isnull(q.Col5,0) AS Col5
FROM    
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col5 ASC, Col3 ASC) rn
    FROM 

    (SELECT 0 AS  Col1, tab34.Col2, tab34.Col4, tab34.Col3, Col5 FROM
            (SELECT PST FROM Func2('x','y')) tab3
        LEFT JOIN

            (SELECT Col2, Col4,Col3,abs(tab33.Value + Col6) AS Value, Col7 AS Col5 FROM

                (SELECT tab11.Col2, tab11.Col4, tab11.Col3, Value FROM
                    (SELECT Col2, Col4, Col3 FROM Table2 WHERE Col8 = 'y' AND Col10 = 1) tab22
                JOIN
                    (SELECT Col2, sum(Value) AS Value, Col4, Col3 FROM Table1 WHERE Col9 = 'x' AND Col8 = 'y' GROUP BY Col2, Col4, Col3) tab11
                ON tab11.Col2 = tab22.Col2 AND tab11.Col4 = tab22.Col4 AND tab11.Col3 = tab22.Col3
                WHERE Value < 0) tab33

            JOIN
                (SELECT Col11, Col6, Col7 FROM dbo.Func1('x','y')) Shifts
            ON Shifts.Col11 = tab33.Col2) tab34 

        ON tab3.PST = tab34.Value
    ) VolData
) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: What happens when you execute it without the `WHERE rn = 1`?

Comment: I never tried that- I get the correct result?? I have that to always select the first result in case one of my joins returns multiple rows. Why is that and how do i fix it??

Comment: Can you supply some example data that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Martin, the example data would be the output from the most-nested SELECT: {0,10,5,-2,10}

Comment: What you are describing is impossible. Please post all results which the innermost query returns. The record with `NULL` values is among them. Also please post the innermost query in all its entirety.

Comment: I meant example source data. Would be best if you included an entire script that populates a table variable and selects from that.

Comment: What you have posted [here works as expected.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72187)

Comment: @Mikael, that is bizarre! When I execute my inner SELECT i do get the values {0,10,5,-2,10}. However when I execute the whole statement I do not get the correct result, but if i leave out the WHERE clase I do....!!

Comment: Actually if you have an all-`NULL` record within the innermost resultset, it's exactly what would be returned, since `SQL Server` orders `NULL` first.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I cannot post all of the code because it's a fairly complex set of JOINs and you will spend more time trying to understand that. I am just treating this as a black-box up to the point where the code returns {0,10,5,-2,10}

Comment: @Porcupine: it does return more. Or your are not telling us everything. Or you're misinterpreting the results. Again, this is impossible. Please run the innermost query with `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT 0 AS col1, ...` and see the record count.

Comment: @Quassnoi, it returns just the one row (and I have used COUNT(*) for that)

Comment: @Porcupine: please post the whole query. Better, make a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Also, why the downvote? It's a valid programming-related question.

Comment: @Quassnoi Not my DV but without some additional details such as actual query or reproducible test case this question does seem a bit of a waste of time participating in.

Comment: The problem is the rn condition is not being included correctly, hence why the query works when the WHERE clause is not included and doesnt work when it is.

Comment: @Martin/everyone- complete sanitised query included.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly answer, please forgive if it is.

Are the row numbers  zero based? What happens if you change the where clause to:

```
WHERE rn = 0
```

?

EDIT: I also noticed that there might be a missing "AS" in the line:

```
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col5 ASC, Col3 ASC) rn
```

Should it be:

```
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col5 ASC, Col3 ASC) AS rn
```

Comment: No, [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) values start from 1.