# Partition BY.... ORDER BY more than one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When using PARTITION BY, in the ORDER BY clause is it possible to order based upon more than one column, like a normal ORDER BY statement?

```
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col0 ORDER BY Col1, Col2)
```

I seem to be getting errors when I ORDER BY more than one column

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check that you have all columns you are ordering by and returning them from the subquery.

Comment: Maybe if you added a "from" clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, there is no problem with your query and I'm betting that if you say to be *seem to be getting errors* is because you are actually running the query with no actual errors but obtaining different values than the ones you expected. Those are not errors. If you want us to help you obtaining the values you want, then you need to change your question to reflect that.

Comment: This is just a comment. I'm sure that he really gets _errors_ but they are not related to an `Over` clause with multiple column order.

Comment: No my query (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948293/odd-result-from-sql-query) wasn't working because I was ordering on more than one column. For certain data it worked, for other data values it didn't work. All data values were valid numbers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - From what I get from the question, op isn't getting actual errors, but data that he/she didn't expect